# pass row to function in design view in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I have a a column in design view called RU. My function name is test. I have 3 row paramaters. When I pass them and breakpoint the function, it seems it never enters it. Yet the column output becomes #error.

```
ru : test([table1].[column1],[table1].[column2],[table1].[column3])  <--all strings

module1:

Option Compare Database

function test(a As string, b as string, c as string) as string
dim send as string
send = "test"
test=send
End function
```

Comment: What do you mean by "column in design view"?

Comment: in query design view, you can select or create a column. My column name is RU and the data behind it : test(.....) <-is the function that populates this column. I pass 3 other rows by column name in this function.

Comment: What happens if you type `?test("a","b","c")` into the immediate window? The problem suggests that the function is not compiling.

Comment: @user719825 Do you have the real example of the function that you are eventually going to use, because this function has no purpose, will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you have "public" on the front of Function if it is in a separate module